# Generating 2D grid indices using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I would like to store the row and column indices of a `3 x 3` list in list. It should look like the following:

```py
rc = [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
```

How can I get this list using a list comprehension in Python?

Comment: Are you sure that your input is a list with size 3*3?

Comment: yes Ras, my list say [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]. i want to save the rows and cols of this list in another list- using list comprehension.

Comment: So, what is the desired output for this sample which you provided?

Comment: As i mentioned, i would like to get an output  [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]  using list comprehension, if it is possible

Answer (score 5):

[Some](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#274-decision) consider multiple `for` loops inside a list comprehension to be poor style. Use `itertools.product()` instead:

```py
from itertools import product

list(product(range(3), repeat=2))
```

This outputs:

```py
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am glad to learn about itertools.product(). This helps!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
 [(x, y) for x in range(3) for y in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, and the input is A, the B can be output as follows:

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
B =[(A[i], A[j]) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  but this outputs:    [([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]), ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]), ([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]), ([4, 5, 6].... I got the answer from Oliver - [(x, y) for x in range(3) for y in range(3)] which works well